# "Recrawl now" in Google Search Console links to a YouTube video, why?

Tags: google-search-console

This screenshot was taken while mousing over Recrawl Now.

Notice that the link in the bottom is for a youtube video.  What is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was an April Fools' prank from Google.  Here is a video of somebody clicking the link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyAjMwN56e8

The is a forum discussion about it [here](https://help.gulshankumar.net/t/introducing-search-console-new-recrawl-now-button/924).

They apparently launched this "feature" on March 31st and some sites [such as this example](https://www.billhartzer.com/pages/google-launches-quick-indexing-feature-google-search-console/) took it seriously.  Google copped to the prank [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/googlewmc/status/981097631458955266):

> Inside, we both know what's been going on. We know the game and ... we were gonna play it.
>
> We hope you had fun with our April Fools link! Wishing you a great start into April!

Comment: As of April 2 at noon MDT it is still showing the pop song link.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford  I'm sure it will come down eventually.   Either when April 1st is over world wide or when they get around to it in the next few days.